# Usage dynamic as result for web API

Tags: c#, dynamic, response, webapi

Is it normal practice to return dynamic or get object type in web API controller methods or should I use custom contract types with validating in requests and general "complete code"?

For example here is code snippet:

```
public dynamic CreateOrUpdate([FromBody]object body)
    {
        return _blService.CreateOrder(body);
    }
```

CreateOrder performs deserializing and saving and returns Id or error.

Here are other methods returning dynamic data. blService returns different anonymous types for list of object or for single object:

```
public dynamic GetOrdersByTypeId([FromQuery]Guid typeId, [FromQuery]int? pageIndex)
{
    return _blService.GetOrdersByTypeId(typeId, pageIndex);
}

public dynamic GetOrderById([FromQuery]Guid id)
{
    return _blService.GetOrderById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While returning `dynamic` works, the general consensus seems to be that you should be returing `IHttpActionResult`, which enables you to use a host of predefined methods (such as `Ok()`, `InternalServerError()`, `BadRequest()`, `NotFound()`, `Redirect()` that, among other things, set the HTTP status code for the request properly before returning.

Also, I would write a few POCOs and return them, but that comes down to a matter of preference. You would need to stick them into a separate project, but it has the advantage that you don't have to update the actual deserialization code when adding properties.

I'm also not a big fan of that `[FromBody]object body`, because using a well-defined type buys you validation that otherwise you will have to implement yourself. Decorating said type with the attributes you find in the `DataAnnotations` namespace would be even better.